# Server Context Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to set up a context variable for rails in a way that I can store it and use on all controllers and actions in my app.

Basically it's a server that have several games. The user chooses 1 game and that goes on `current_game`. Depending on the value of `current_game` the app loads different stuff from the data base.

Is there a way I can make it?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can using session variables, read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Besides session, is there another way to handle this?

Comment: When you're user are logged in you app, store the information in the database and erase it when user log out. But session variabler work fine :D

Comment: That's my second option, because there is no user login, so there is not really a session. I was hoping I could make it without changing the database :(

Comment: But if user are not logged how can you retrieve the data in db for each user ? ^^ You can create a session just when user choose the game he want's to play

Comment: A session is created for each visitor. They do not have to log in and you do not need a database because this is all done using cookies by default.